# Locate all graphics

Tags: vba, ms-word, visual-studio-macros

I have 100+ Word documents each with 1000+ pictures. I need to "view" all of them one by one in a doc and also count the total number of pics in a document.

I tried using "Find Graphics" ---"^g". However it does not locate all the pics.

After experimentation, I realized that if a graphic's Wrap Text value is set to "In Line with Text" only then it is treated as a graphic and gets located in a Find!

Is there any way to locate all the pictures in a document one after the other and also get a count all of them in one document?

Comment: have you tried anything on your own, I mean record a macro or serach in internet for any solution? in general- there is `InlineShapes and Shapes collection` which you are looking for. Try with simple `For each loop` in reference to both type of shapes. And something more- please see [this info for how to accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)(if applicable for any of your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view the total number of images in a document, you can use something like the following:

```
MsgBox ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
```

A wrapper you could use to loop through them is:

```
For Each iShape In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    stuff
Next
```

One option is to step into the macro and use F8 to step through the code.